# Webpack externals - aren't all dependencies already external?

Tags: npm, webpack, package, external

When bundling with webpack, we can choose to put certain dependencies in the externals section, meaning they will not be bundled into our build. But if we are creating an NPM package with webpack, shouldn't *all* the dependencies be externalized? In a dev environment, when installing the package, all the package's dependencies will be installed as well. So we should certainly list them all in the `webpack.config.js` under externals, so as to minimize our bundle size and not bundle these dependencies which will be installed on an `npm install` anyway, right? What is a scenario where we want to bundle our dependencies into an npm package?

Comment: What do you mean *"creating an NPM package"*, exactly? Webpack is for creating bundles to deploy a website, not a package for other people to depend on. Generally the dependencies of the front end build *won't* be installed in production (production may just be a static file server).

Comment: I mean when you are trying to write a plugin.  I've been seeing a lot of people write react components as npm packages, but they're using webpack to build them (using babel) - like [this plugin](https://github.com/mhasbie/react-leaflet-measure) for react-leaflet for example.  it is a react component, built with webpack, designed for use in other developers' projects.

Comment: Well you can see how they manage their deps, they *do* externalise the peer dependencies.

Comment: Right.  It makes sense to externalise peer dependencies, as you expect these dependencies to be in the dev environment of whoever is using your package.  But isn't the same true of the regular dependencies, just by virtue of the fact that they are installed when your package is installed?

Comment: They have two peer deps and one normal dep, all externalised. The rest are dev deps, used to develop and build but not needed in prod (and therefore not installed by packages that depend on it).